# RSPEC throws NameError: uninitialized constant error for shared module after Rails 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently upgraded to Rails 5 and am encountering an error on development that is (what I expect, anyway) related to loading a shared module.

The error is `Rspec: NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES` and occurs when running Rspec tests that use a method that uses a shared module.

The path for the shared module is: `lib/shared/truthy.rb` and the module code is below.

`module Shared
  module Truthy
    def self.boolean(value)
      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
    end
  end
end`

The path for the file that uses the method that accesses this module is: `engines/events/app/controllers/events/events_controller.rb`and the method that uses the shared module is below.

`def official_event?
   Shared::Truthy.boolean(params[:event][:official])
 end`

This wasn't throwing any error prior to upgrading to Rails 5, so it's safe to say there's no issue with the Rspec test.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this error is a result of Rails 5 [removing uses of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20363).